# MicroRuleEngine value from another object

Tags: c#, expression-trees, member, rule-engine

Been looking a bit at the MicroRuleEngine found here:

https://github.com/runxc1/MicroRuleEngine

In the one of the unittests, the following code exists:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void ChildPropertyBooleanMethods()
    {
        Order order = this.GetOrder();
        Rule rule = new Rule()
        { 
            MemberName = "Customer.FirstName",
            Operator = "EndsWith",//Regular method that exists on string.. As a note expression methods are not available
            Inputs = new List<object> { "ohn" }
        };
        MRE engine = new MRE();
        var childPropCheck = engine.CompileRule<Order>(rule);
        bool passes = childPropCheck(order);
        Assert.IsTrue(passes);

        order.Customer.FirstName = "jane";
        passes = childPropCheck(order);
        Assert.IsFalse(passes);
    }
```

which will test that Order.FirstName ends with "ohn", so long so good... but how would I change the MRE-code so that instead of testing against a string litteral, I'd test against the value on another object?? Someting in the line of:

```
    Rule rule = new Rule()
        { 
            MemberName = "Customer.FirstName",
            Operator = "EndsWith",//Regular method that exists on string.. As a note expression methods are not available
            Inputs = new List<object> { new MemberValue<SomeClass>(someclass, "PartOfName") }
        };
```

where:

```
class SomeClass {
    string PartOfName {get; set;}
}
```

and:

```
class MemberValue<T>(T instance, string memberName) {
    ...
}
```

I'm a newbie to ExpressionTrees, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you just use `someclass.PartOfName`?

Comment: Can't just use someclass.PartOfName, because the rule definition comes from a DB and therefore exists as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of a property when you have its name as a string, use reflection:

```
object GetPropertyValue(object target, string propertyName)
{
    return target.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(target);
}
```